# What healing mod is being used in this world of warcraft video?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've always played DPS in my time playing WoW. I recently rolled a holy priest and am interested in the HPS game. The add-on the healer in this video is using seems to be super efficient:

[image]
<sub>Image found in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDHIRS-WcjY), containing a spoiler strategy for defeating Hagara in the Dragon Soul raid on heroic mode. If you do not want to have this spoiled for you, avoid watching the video.</sub>

Can anyone vouch for what it is? Or give an answer for some AddOns I can download that are very popular with healing types, particularly priests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like a custom [Grid](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/grid) layout with [Clique](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/clique) for click casting. This is what I use. I prefer making my own bar layouts and debuff trackers over Healbot. Grid has a ton of extra addons to make it even more robust.

If you watch the UI video that the same user has posted [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_gkdUbcnOk) he confirms that he uses Grid.

Comment: Looks like grid to me, so +1